# Can I secure a GIT repository using a password?

Tags: git, security, passwords, clone

Is it possible to secure my GIT repository using a password? e.g. when I clone the repository, I want to get prompted to enter an password otherwise, I cannot clone it.

I am using a GIT repository in my local area network and I often clone repositories from the server onto my local PC. I am concerned that anybody in the network can clone the repository and access confidential source code.

Comment: Where is your git repository being hosted? Is it accessible through both HTTPS and SSH?

Comment: It is in my local network on a server.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/694504/how-to-set-up-a-secure-git-repository

Comment: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/

Answer (score 1):

You're likely running the Git daemon, which  offers no encryption or authentication. This is only ideal for public read-only mirrors of your repositories.

For a closed network, using HTTP and HTTPS instead of the Git daemon will provide a slight performance increase, plus firewall penetration and proxy support. HTTPS requires a trusted TLS certificate and additional configuration.

The most secure method is to use SSH, which provides strong encryption and both password and key authentication.

[Learn More](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) and see these [instructions for setting up an SSH git server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server#Small-Setups).